# move content including subfolders between folders in unix

Tags: unix

I have a path like this which contain folders and subfolders:

`~/public_html/myfolder/myfolder/`

how do I move all the content from 
`~/public_html/myfolder/myfolder/` to 
`~/public_html/myfolder/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
mv ~/public_html/myfolder/myfolder/* ~/public_html/myfolder
```

Run `man mv` for more details.